# Why is the touchable area so small of this TouchableOpacity?

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchableopacity

When I press the `TouchableOpacity`, it highlights, but a little over half of the time, it doesn't log `press`.

Why is the touchable area so small? It feels like it is only `1 x 1` pixel.

I already tried quite a few things, such as using a `<View>` wrapper and setting the `width` and `height` of the `TouchableOpacity` component.

```
<List.Item
      onPress={undefined}
      right={() => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => console.log('press')}
              style={{
                top: 18,
                right: 10,
                position: 'absolute',
              }}
            >
              <FontAwesome name="trash" size={16} color="#FF0000" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`TouchableOpacity` has the size of the content in this example which means if the icon is very small then your touchable area will be very small. I usually set a square sized container style for icons and increase the size when necessary

```
<List.Item
  onPress={undefined}
  right={() => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => console.log('press')}
          style={{
            top: 18,
            right: 10,
            position: 'absolute',
            height: 20,
            width: 20
          }}
        >
          <FontAwesome name="trash" size={16} color="#FF0000" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried that and it didn't change the situation for me. Also, it shows it is touching it, but doesn't call `console.log()`